# Endogenous variable Instrument

Tags: econometrics, stata, binary-data

I am confused about running an iv regression 
My endogenous variable is a dummy variable i-e earlychildbearing=1 if ageatfirstbirth<20

My second stage equation is the standard child health equation.

My question is ,is it okay to use the standard iv regress command since my endogenous variable is a binary variable?

Comment: Is your outcome binary or continuous?

Comment: My outcome variable in the second stage is continuous. Child health is measured through height for age and weight for age indicators.

Answer (score 1):

In Stata, you can use `etregress/treatreg` to handle the case where you have a binary endogenous covariate. This approach imposes more structure, the main benefit of which is increased precision of estimation. The main cost is a greater chance of misspecification. If the errors are heteroskedastic, the standard IV remains consistent, but this treatment effects estimator will be inconsistent.

Comment: @user31960 Does this make sense?